# pagination module not found in the Kohana::modules() in bootstrap file

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

hi i'm new to kohana when i'm trying to use kohana pagination module i got error like this

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Pagination' not found
```

later i look in `bootstrap` file then there is no  `Pagination` module in `Kohana::modules()`

my bootstrap file is like this

```
Kohana::modules(array(
 'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication
 'cache'      => MODPATH.'cache',      // Caching with multiple backends
'codebench'  => MODPATH.'codebench',  // Benchmarking tool
 'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access
 'image'      => MODPATH.'image',      // Image manipulation
 'orm'        => MODPATH.'orm',        // Object Relationship Mapping
 'unittest'   => MODPATH.'unittest',   // Unit testing
 'userguide'  => MODPATH.'userguide',  // User guide and API documentation
));
```

where can i get module and how to add it and enable ???

please give some clarity

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that for the version 3.2 no such (stable) pagination module exists. I'm not following kohana that closely but can remember that this class takes it's time to keep steady with the pace of development.

You can find a (probably working) 3.2 development version here: https://github.com/kohana/pagination/tree/3.2/develop

Answer (score 0):

Installing modules to Kohana is fairly easy due to Kohana's [Cascading Filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files).

First, you will want to download the [pagination module](https://github.com/kohana/pagination) from GitHub using the download as ZIP option on the downloads page. Extract the files to a folder named `pagination` in your Kohana installation's modules directory.

Next, you will need to add a line to your modules array pointing the name of the module to its path. You should end up with;

```php
Kohana::modules(array(
    'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication
    'cache'      => MODPATH.'cache',      // Caching with multiple backends
    'codebench'  => MODPATH.'codebench',  // Benchmarking tool
    'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access
    'image'      => MODPATH.'image',      // Image manipulation
    'orm'        => MODPATH.'orm',        // Object Relationship Mapping
    'unittest'   => MODPATH.'unittest',   // Unit testing
    'userguide'  => MODPATH.'userguide',  // User guide and API documentation
    'pagination' => MODPATH.'pagination', // Added pagination module 
));
```

Bear in mind that this module was built for Kohana 3.1, and was last touched 2 years ago.